# Bundle exec rake test is not producing results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rubygems

I am running all my tests that I have created/scaffolded for my controllers. I also have test_helper.rb. I have the following gems installed for testing:

`104 group :test do
105   gem 'capybara'
106   gem 'vcr', '~> 2.9'
107   gem 'webmock', '~> 2.1'
108   gem 'minitest'
109   gem 'shoulda-matchers'
110   gem 'resque_spec'
111   gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', '~> 2.2.4', require: 'stripe_mock'
112   gem 'rspec_junit_formatter' # for circleci.com
113   gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
114   gem 'mini_backtrace', '0.1.3'
115   gem 'guard', '2.14.0'
116   gem 'guard-minitest', '2.3.1'
117 end`

Here is my test_helper.rb file

`1 require 'simplecov'
  2 SimpleCov.start do #'rails'
  3 add_filter '/spec/'
  4 add_filter '/config/'
  5 add_filter '/lib/'
  6 add_filter '/vendor/'
  7 
  8 add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
  9 add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
 10 add_group 'Helpers', 'app/helpers'
 11 add_group 'Mailers', 'app/mailers'
 12 end
 13 
 14 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
 15 require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
 16 require 'rails/test_help'
 17 
 18 class ActiveSupport::TestCase
 19 # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
 20                                        fixtures :all
 21

 22 # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
 23 private
 24 
 25 # Returns true inside an integration test.
 26 def integration_test?
 27 defined?(post_via_redirect)
 28 end
 29 
 30 end`

The majority of my controllers themselves have:

`1 module Dashboard
2 class ZoneTypesController < Dashboard::MainDashboardController`

In my test/controllers:

`1 require 'test_helper'
 2 class UnitTemplatesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase`

When I run "bundle exec rake test", nothing shows up, no errors, no reporting of how many tests were passed, etc. I don't know what to do. I've also looked at the other stack overflow questions regarding this problem and none of them are helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
bundle exec rake test RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you